# Correct Syntax for Order By with Two Variables?

Tags: vb.net, linq, sql-order-by, vb.net-2010

```
phone = From objPhone As PersonPhoneEntity In sortedPhoneList
Where objPhone.PersonPhone.EffectiveEndDate > DateTime.Now And
objPhone.PersonPhone.EffectiveStartDate <= DateTime.Now 
Order By objPhone.PersonPhone.EffectiveEndDate Descending
```

Now I need to add a second order by argument for EffectiveStartDate proceeding the sort by end date above. I have tried simply putting a coma in between the to order by's because that is what resharper and vs2010 is accepting but that does not seem to be working when I debug it. I would appreciate anyone helping me out in finding the correct way to order by 2 variables.

Comment: "that does not seem to be working" doesn't give us any information about what's going wrong.

Comment: Is it a syntax error, because the comma is the separator for multiple orderby clauses in LINQ.

Comment: I noticed you have `Order By` instead of `orderby`, it is one word in LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well (first order by `EffectiveStartDate`, then by `EffectiveEndDate` (descending) it should be this:

```
phone = From objPhone As PersonPhoneEntity In sortedPhoneList 
        Where objPhone.PersonPhone.EffectiveEndDate > DateTime.Now
          And objPhone.PersonPhone.EffectiveStartDate <= DateTime.Now 
        Order By objPhone.PersonPhone.EffectiveStartDate,
                 objPhone.PersonPhone.EffectiveEndDate Descending
```

After the `Order By` clause you can just repeat column names (possibly followed by `Descending`) separated by commas.